# Why won't display: flex; and justify-content: center; center this slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want this slideshow to be centered within its grid-area.

I tried using flexbox on the grid area to center it, but that didn't work. 
The img elements need to have position: absolute; so that they can overlap and the fade effect will work. (Unless you can show me another way).

Here is the Javascript that creates the slideshow:

```js
var curIndex = 0,
  imgDuration = 3000,
  slider = document.getElementById("slider"),
  slides = slider.childNodes;

imgArray = [
  'beer buckets.jpg',
  "beer and rita's.jpg",
  'fried shrimp.jpg',
  'beer and bloody mary.jpg',
  'tamales.jpg'
];

console.log(slides);

function buildSlideShow(arr) {
  for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = arr[i];
    slider.appendChild(img);
  }
}

function slideShow() {

  function fadeIn(e) {
    e.className = "fadeIn";
  };

  function fadeOut(e) {
    e.className = "";
  };


  fadeOut(slides[curIndex]);
  curIndex++;
  if (curIndex === slides.length) {
    curIndex = 1;
  }

  fadeIn(slides[curIndex]);

  setTimeout(function() {
    slideShow();
  }, imgDuration);
};

buildSlideShow(imgArray);
slideShow();
```

```css
#slider {
  position: relative;
}

#slider>img {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#slider img {
  transition: opacity 1.5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#slider img.fadeIn {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='slider'>

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue, along with a clear description of the issue and the goal. See [ask].

Comment: No flex rule is found in your css, your images are positioned absolutely which flex centering will not affect